# Tab Order in QWidget and its child Widgets

Tags: c++, qt, focus, qwidget

I want to create a GUI for a address book. There i have a problem with the Tab Order inside my Create-A-New-Contact Widget (lets call it **NewContactWidget**). It looks like this:

[image]

I want to reuse the "row" containing the **Group** settings. So i decide to create a own widget (lets call it **GroupsWidget**) and include it as a child widget here. I use the Designer inside QCreator. I define a empty QWidget inside the **NewContactWidget** as a placeholder for the **GroupsWidget**. After this I edit the TabOrder:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. QWidget (placeholder for **GroupsWidget**)
4. Cancel
5. Save

To do so, I have to change the focus policy of the QWidget Placeholder from **NoFocus** to **TabFocus**

After this I define the Tab Order inside the **GroupsWidget**:

1. Options
2. Add Button (+)
3. Remove button (-)

Now the Problem:
Tabbing through the **NewContactWidget** will result in

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Cancel
4. Save
5. Options
6. Add Button (+)
7. Remove button (-)

instead of

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Options
4. Add Button (+)
5. Remove button (-)
6. Cancel
7. Save

So I add a event listener to the **GroupsWidget** to set the focus to **Option** ComboBox when ever the **GroupsWidget** got the focus. This work a little bit. Now I have the following result:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Options
4. Add Button (+)
5. Remove button (-)

No chance to go to **Save** or **Cancel** Button

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: What do you mean by placeholder? I have implemented your logic and by default the tab order is the one you want

Comment: In the following link is my test code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/fc99d9a69cd6031d9784e0f5939a8cbb

Comment: I use the **GroupsWidget** a custom widget. Tow seperate +.ui files. and one included into the other. https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Comment: Well if you want help provide a [mcve] for example sharing the .uis

Comment: You are promoting a widget but the behavior must be the same as my code since the promotion only changes the creation of the widget with its new widget.

Comment: Try the same with the Designer inside the QCreator-IDE. I have to use this way for historical reasons .. I don't like it neither. I prefer the way you do it, but i cant :(

Comment: I have used Qt Designer with Qt Creator and I get the same as my previous code, my last test can be found in: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/55720316

Comment: I've try it and it works. But I don't use the **QDialogButtonBox** (its new to me, but awsome. thx) I use two QPushButton. And then you got the same problem.

Comment: I have only unchecked the autoDefaut property of the QPushButton, both examples you find it in: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/55720316

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191954/discussion-between-marcus-and-eyllanesc).